# Accessing Highcharts methods in Rally chart

Tags: highcharts, rally

I'm working on a custom burnup report for my department, and I have almost everything working. The last thing being requested is to have a box drawn on the chart around an iteration if it's considered a "hardening" or "regression" iteration, like so:

[image: example image]

From the Highcharts API, the `addPlotBand()` method seemed promising (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-addplotband/) example), but I'm having a hell of a time figuring out how I can access the Highcharts methods from my Rally chart object.

When I try something like this:

```
myChart.xAxis[0].addPlotBland({
  from: 1.0,
  to: 3.0,
  color: '#FCFFC5',
  id: 'plot-band-1'
});
```

I get an error because xAxis is undefined. That makes sense, because myChart is a Rally.ui.chart.Chart object. I just don't know if there's a way to access the Highcharts methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add plot bands directly in the "chartConfig" of the `rallychart` component like so:

```
chartConfig : {
    xAxis: {
        plotBands : [{
            from  : 1.0,
            to    : 3.0,
            color : '#FCFFC5',
            id    : 'plot-band-1'
        }]
    }
}
```

But if you need to add a plotband to an existing chart, use:

`myChart.down('highchart').chartConfig.xAxis.plotBands.push(bandConfig);`

Comment: Yes, that did it. I didn't realize I could access the chartConfig property like that. +1 for explaining both how to add a plot band at configure time and to an existing chart.

Comment: One problem I've run into with this approach - when I change the release, I'm redrawing the chart. I call this.remove('myChart') to remove it, and then I create a new version with Ext.create(). The first time I do this, the plot bands render fine. Any subsequent attempts, the plot bands no longer render. Is there a better way I should be redrawing the chart?

Comment: After using the second method to add a plot band, you may need to refresh the chart. Use: myChart.down('highchart').update();

Comment: Adding this comment in case it helps someone else. I refactored my code to use the first method (setting the plotBands as part of the chart config). I'm still looping through my array to determine where the plot bands are needed, and then setting plotBands: myArray. Doing it that way works correctly, even if I have to remove and re-draw the chart. Don't know why I didn't think of that the first time.